# How much gas does looking up block.timestamp consume?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price

Trying to get some insight as to whether or not it's more optimal to call block.timestamp repeatedly for comparisons or to set a (memory) variable to hold the value and use it instead.

I've looked at the gas cost table here:

http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/account-types-gas-and-transactions.html

but am not certain about where block.timestamp fits in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TIMESTAMP op code costs 2 gas, according to the yellow paper (https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), Appendix G and Appendix H.